# Flex image transition animation

Tags: image, apache-flex, transition

I want to implement horizontal image transition while changing image in slide show? HOw can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at flex effects?

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=createeffects_4.html

For example, WipeRight might do something similar to what you're looking for, although your question isn't terribly clear:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/effects/WipeRight.html